# How can I delete each row (one at the time) containing a file name when there is no ID identifying each row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found this section of the code online, I am just trying to complete and use it for my project.

In the script below, I tried to add an ID to identify a row, but it only reference the first row. Once that row (the first row) is deleted, the following rows cannot be deleted.

I have done some extensive research online but I could not find anything that could help me. Do you have any suggestions?

Below is the code for the table, then the script to delete the row(s) containing the file name a user would like to delete. Below is the script where I actually delete the row. I added `id='link'` to identify the row.

```js
var markup = "<tr id ='link'><td>" + result + "</td><td><a  href='#' onclick='DeleteFile(\"" + result + "\")' ><span class='fa fa-trash fa-fw'></span></a></td></tr>"; // Binding the file name

$("#ListofFiles tbody").append(markup);
$('#Files').val('');
$('#FileBrowse').find("*").prop("disabled", false);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h4>
    Attachments:
  </h4>
  <div id="FileBrowse">
    <!--Start of HTML input control button-->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="file" id="Files" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input type="button" id="UploadBtn" class="btn btn-danger" value="Upload" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--End of HTML input control button-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div id="progressbar-5">
        <div class="progress-label">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br />
  <div class="row">
    <!-- Start of HTML table to show the files list-->
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <table class="table" id="ListofFiles">
        <tr>
          <th>
            Files
          </th>
          <th>
            Action
          </th>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End of HTML table showing the files list-->
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
</div>
```

Comment: Your script is incomplete. This could be a duplicate of [Why does Jquery only affect the first div element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16889752/4642212). Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. Learn how to traverse the DOM (which isn’t limited to selecting IDs), and learn how to reference elements (what is the return value of `$("#ListofFiles tbody").append(markup)`? Use the console.)

Comment: if you pass `this` to DeleteFile (which we can't see btw, so we're not sure what it does) you'd have a reference to the button. You could make `result` an attribute of the button, so you could then retrieve it easily. At the same time, you'd have a reference to the button itself, and you can use that to locate the table row which is its parent, and delete that row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function to do this. We iterate over each cell, determine if it includes the filename, and if it does we delete the row by finding the cell in the DOM using its index, moving to its parent element (tr) and removing it.

```
function deleteFile(filename) {
  $("#ListofFiles tr td").each((index, cell) => {
  cell.textContent.includes(filename) && 
  $("#ListofFiles tr td").eq(index).parent().remove();
  });
}

deleteFile("file.ext");
```

```js
let result = "file.ext";

var markup = "<tr id ='link'><td>" + result + "</td><td><a  href='#' onclick='DeleteFile(\"" + result + "\")' ><span class='fa fa-trash fa-fw'></span></a></td></tr>"; // Binding the file name

$("#ListofFiles tbody").append(markup);

$('#Files').val('');
$('#FileBrowse').find("*").prop("disabled", false);

function deleteFile(filename) {
  $("#ListofFiles tr td").each((index, cell) => {
      cell.textContent.includes(filename) && $("#ListofFiles tr td").eq(index).parent().remove();
  });
}

deleteFile("file.ext");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h4>
    Attachments:
  </h4>
  <div id="FileBrowse">
    <!--Start of HTML input control button-->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="file" id="Files" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input type="button" id="UploadBtn" class="btn btn-danger" value="Upload" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--End of HTML input control button-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div id="progressbar-5">
        <div class="progress-label">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br />
  <div class="row">
    <!-- Start of HTML table to show the files list-->
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <table class="table" id="ListofFiles">
        <tr>
          <th>
            Files
          </th>
          <th>
            Action
          </th>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End of HTML table showing the files list-->
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @zfrisch. The solution you provided solved my problem.