# Weird Jquery only add class in one id not applying to all ids

Tags: jquery

Here's the jquery code

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     jQuery("#ktsttestimonial_list_style").addClass('review');
        });
```

[image: output as image here]

Comment: Ids have to be **unique**. Use a class instead or `$(".testimonials_list_area div").addClass()`

Comment: Not weird at all. See the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) telling: *Each id value must be used only once within a document. If more than one element has been assigned the same ID, queries that use that ID will only select the first matched element in the DOM.*

Comment: assigning one identifier for many selectors is a mistake. each element must have a unique identifier.

Comment: Okay I got now ID is unique it cannot add on multiple ids. Thanks
$(".testimonials_list_area div").addClass() still wont on me it will add class to all div inside the id.

Comment: Duplicate of [Why does Jquery only affect the first div element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16889752/why-does-jquery-only-affect-the-first-div-element).

Answer (score 0):

You should get to grips with some basic HTML first.  W3Schools is a good place to start.

Having said that, if you haven't got the knowledge of these things, it's going to be difficult for you to implement what you've been told in the comments.  To that end, see the below snippet for an example of what I think you're trying to do.

Note that *ktsttestimonials_list_style* is the value of the **class** attribute for each div, there is no id attribute (it doesn't look like you need an id from the little screenshot you posted).

```js
function changeme(){
  $('.ktsttestimonials_list_style').addClass('review');
}
```

```css
.review{
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ktsttestimonials_list_style">Div 1</div>
<div class="ktsttestimonials_list_style">Div 2</div>
<div class="ktsttestimonials_list_style">Div 3</div>
<div class="ktsttestimonials_list_style">Div 4</div>
<div class="ktsttestimonials_list_style">Div 5</div>

<button onclick="changeme()">Change Color</button>
```