# How to disabled buttons using JQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, css, function, button

**So I wanted to make a other buttons **disabled** when a button was once clicked**

```
      $(".btnA").click(function () {
                $("#con1").show(1000, "swing");
                $("#con2").attr("disabled", true);
            });
```

**Can I make a #con2 disabled if the btnA is clicked?
Do I need to have a if..else condition to do this?
Is it possible that when a button is clicked in jquery, other buttons will disabled?**
**Edit Post**

```js
 <script>
              //Show
        $(".btnA").click(function () {
            $("#baguio").show(1000, "swing");
            $(".btnB").attr("disabled", true);
             $(".btnC").attr("disabled", true);
        });
        $(".btnB").click(function () {
            $("#SF").show(1000, "swing");
            $(".btnC").attr("disabled", true);
            $(".btnA").attr("disabled", true);
        });
        $(".btnC").click(function () {
            $("#vigan").show(1000, "swing");
             $(".btnB").attr("disabled", true);
            $(".btnA").attr("disabled", true);
        });
        
        //Hide
         $(".closeA").click(function () {
            $("#baguio").hide(1000, "swing");
        });
        $(".closeB").click(function () {
            $("#SF").hide(1000, "swing");
        });
        $(".closeC").click(function () {
            $("#vigan").hide(1000, "swing");
        });
```

```css
<style>

  #a, #baguio {
            background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)), url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/6464126/pexels-photo-6464126.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940");
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center;

        }

        #b, #SF {
            background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)),url("https://dxjamgtjhgl48.cloudfront.net/uploads/article_inline_image/attachment/5bd7af80372064181b00011e/01_La_Union__zellylacuachera_.jpg");
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center;
        }

        #c, #vigan {
            background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)), url("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/0e/d6/0e/0ed60ecbf77b9fffc4c8fc67fac688a5.jpg");
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center;
        }
   .col-2 {
            margin: 5px;
            height: 350px;
            width: 250px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: #bf9b93;
            margin: 5px;
            border-radius: 35px;
            box-shadow: 5px 10px 18px #888888;
        }
        .btn {
            border-color: #f27f30;
            color: #fff;
            backdrop-filter: blur(1px);
            border-radius: 30px;
            padding: 1rem 2rem;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }

        .btn:hover {
            background-color:  #f27f30;
        }


</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<body>

<!--Here is the card-->
<h2 style="text-align: center; margin-bottom: 15px;">Bus Route</h2>
                <strong style="text-align: center;">Be advised that due to the COVID-19 advisory we are limited to offer you our services</strong>
                <h3 style="text-align: center;">Welcome to North!</h3>
 <div class="row align-items-center d-flex justify-content-center">
                                <div class="col-2" id="a">
                                    <h3>Cordillera </h3>
                                    <a class="btn btnA" data-toggle="collapse" href="#baguio">Baguio City</a>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-2" id="b">
                                    <h3>La Union</h3>
                                    <a class="btn btnB" data-toggle="collapse" href="#SF">San Fabian</a>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-2" id="c">
                                    <h3>Ilocos Norte</h3>
                                    <an class="btn btnC" href="#vigan" data-toggle="collapse">Vigan City</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            <!--When button was once clicked this will show-->
                            
                             <div id="baguio" class="collapse here">
                        <h3>Welcome to Baguio City!</h3>
                        <h4>Where are you from?</h4>
                        <center>
                        <select class="form-select w-50" aria-label="Default select example">
                            <option value="1">Region 1</option>
                            <option value="2">Region 2</option>
                            <option value="3">Region 3</option>
                          </select>
                        </center>
                        <div class = "row align-items-center">
                            <div class = "col-md-6">
                                <table class = "table-bordered">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th colspan = "2"><h3>Point to Point</h3></th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <h4>VIP</h4>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li>1,000 php per head </li>
                                                <li>Premium Airconditioner Bus </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <h4>Regular</h4>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li>500 php per head </li>
                                                <li>Airconditioner Bus </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>

                            <div class = "col-md-6">
                                <table class = "table-bordered">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th colspan="2"><h3>Per Terminal</h3></th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <h4>VIP</h4>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>1600 php per head </li>
                                            <li>Premium Airconditioner Bus </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <h4>Regular</h4>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>300 php per head </li>
                                            <li>Airconditioner Bus </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </td>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <p>
                        <br>    Present your Student/Senior/PWD ID upon paying to get the 20% discount on fare according to
                        <br>    Republic Act No. 11314
                        <br>    Republic Act No. 10754 
                        <br>    Republic Act No. 9994
                        </p>
                        <center> <button class = "btn closeA">Close</button></center>
                       
                    </div>
                
                    <!--San Fernando-->
                    <div id="SF" class="collapse here">
                        <h3>Welcome to San Fabian!</h3>
                        <h4>Where are you from?</h4>
                        <center>
                        <select class="form-select w-50" aria-label="Default select example">
                            <option value="1">Region 1</option>
                            <option value="2">Region 2</option>
                            <option value="3">Region 3</option>
                          </select>
                        </center>
                        <div class = "row align-items-center">
                            <div class = "col-md-6">
                                <table class = "table-bordered">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th colspan = "2"><h3>Point to Point</h3></th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <h4>VIP</h4>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li>1,000 php per head </li>
                                                <li>Premium Airconditioner Bus </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <h4>Regular</h4>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li>500 php per head </li>
                                                <li>Airconditioner Bus </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>

                            <div class = "col-md-6">
                                <table class = "table-bordered">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th colspan="2"><h3>Per Terminal</h3></th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <h4>VIP</h4>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>1600 php per head </li>
                                            <li>Premium Airconditioner Bus </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <h4>Regular</h4>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>300 php per head </li>
                                            <li>Airconditioner Bus </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </td>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <p>
                        <br>    Present your Student/Senior/PWD ID upon paying to get the 20% discount on fare according to
                        <br>    Republic Act No. 11314
                        <br>    Republic Act No. 10754 
                        <br>    Republic Act No. 9994
                        </p>
                        <center> <button class = "btn closeB">Close</button></center>
                    </div>

                    <!--Vigan-->
                    <div id="vigan" class="collapse here">
                        <h3>Welcome to Vigan</h3>
                        <h4>Where are you from?</h4>
                        <center>
                        <select class="form-select w-50" aria-label="Default select example">
                            <option value="1">Region 1</option>
                            <option value="2">Region 2</option>
                            <option value="3">Region 3</option>
                          </select>
                        </center>
                        <div class = "row align-items-center">
                            <div class = "col-md-6">
                                <table class = "table-bordered">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th colspan = "2"><h3>Point to Point</h3></th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <h4>VIP</h4>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li>1,000 php per head </li>
                                                <li>Premium Airconditioner Bus </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <h4>Regular</h4>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li>500 php per head </li>
                                                <li>Airconditioner Bus </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>

                            <div class = "col-md-6">
                                <table class = "table-bordered">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th colspan="2"><h3>Per Terminal</h3></th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <h4>VIP</h4>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>1600 php per head </li>
                                            <li>Premium Airconditioner Bus </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <h4>Regular</h4>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>300 php per head </li>
                                            <li>Airconditioner Bus </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </td>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <p>
                        <br>    Present your Student/Senior/PWD ID upon paying to get the 20% discount on fare according to
                        <br>    Republic Act No. 11314
                        <br>    Republic Act No. 10754 
                        <br>    Republic Act No. 9994
                        </p>
                        <center> <button class = "btn closeC">Close</button></center>
                    </div>
```

**So the other button is not working, what I need my code to do is to disable the .btnB and .btnC when the .btnA was once clicked**

Comment: Does this not work? What do you mean by “_a_ `#con2`”? There is only _one_ `#con2`, _the_ `#con2`. If you have multiple buttons with the same ID `#con2` and are wondering why `$("#con2").attr("disabled", true);` only affects the first, this is a [duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+jquery+duplicate+id+targets+only+first) of [Why does Jquery only affect the first div element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16889752/4642212).

Comment: $("#con2").attr("disabled", true);

it doesn't work on my HTML like it didn't disable that certain button.

Comment: What does this give you: `console.log($("[id=con2]").length)` if it's 0 you don't have a `id=con2` element, if it's more than 1, then you have duplicate IDs and it's acting only on the first.

Comment: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn’t Work”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616/289905) Is your `<script>` _above_ your HTML with no `defer` attribute and no `DOMContentLoaded` or `load` listener? See [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as `getElementById` not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/4642212). Please try using the [debugging capabilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript) of your browser, [edit] your question and provide a [mre], including all _errors_, demonstrate _your research and attempts_.

Comment: Your edit doesn’t make it clear _where_ your scripts are, as implied in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will leave my previous answer below since that is the answer based on your question at that time.

However, since you posted more codes now, ill update my answer.

Can you please change:

`<a class="btn btnB" data-toggle="collapse" href="#SF">San Fabian</a>`

Into the code below:

`<button type="button" class="btn btnB" data-toggle="collapse">San Fabian</button>`

Do the same on `btnC`.

The reason for this is that because the `btnB` and `btnC` elements are anchor links and not a button.

==================================

It seems like your code is running.
Can you try running the snippet below:

```js
$(".btnA").click(function () {
            $("#con1").show(1000, "swing");
            $("#con2").attr("disabled", true);
        });
```

```css
#con1 { display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" class="btnA" value="btnA">
<input type="button" id="con1" value="con1">
<input type="button" id="con2" value="con2">
```

Comment: the snippet run but in my codes it doesn't

Comment: is there any chance that you have two elements that have the same `con2` id?

Comment: @Biax20 then you'll need to include a [mcve] snippet in your question to show us what you've done.  It should demonstrate the issue.

Comment: con2 id doesn't have any same elements but it will also open a div when once clicked.

Comment: Btw I am new to this website so I don't know how to use code snippet i haven't discovered it yet.

Comment: @Biax20 See [How to create Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/4642212).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah of course you can disable a button by clicking another button in jQuery. Try this code. Just pay attention, "btnA" is the **id** of a button element

```
  $("#btnA").click(function () {
                  $("#con2").prop('disabled', true);
            });
```

Why do you use the **input** tag to create a **button**?! Do you have a special reason?

```
<button id="btnA" type="button">btnA</button>
<button id="con2" type="button">con2</button>
```

I hope it would be helpful.